# remove the 3 dots in jquery datepicker alt

Tags: jquery, yii

i am using jquery datepicker through YII framework and using an image .
this image have `title` and `alt` and i could not remove them

here's my code in YII to display the image

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
'name' => 'sso_register[dob]',
//'model' => $model,
'attribute' => 'dob',
'value' => $dbText,
'options' => array(
'changeMonth' => true,
'changeYear' => true,
'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
'yearRange' => "-100:+0",
'maxDate' => '31/12/2007', //day can choose >= tomorrow
'buttonImage' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/date_picker.png',
'buttonImageOnly' => true,
'showButtonPanel' => false,
'showOn' => 'button',
'altField' => '',
),
'htmlOptions' => array(
'class' => 'inputfield-middleside-date',
'readonly' => 'true',
'style' => 'position: relative; z-index: 100;',
'tabindex' => '7',
'alt'=>'',
'title'=>'',
)
));
```

any way to remove those 3 dots in image alt attribute on all browsers ?
Thank you

Comment: Which three dots? Am I the only one who didn't see them?

Comment: put your mouse over the image , the iamge alt and title is 3 dots :(

Comment: Which image? There is no image in this question. Also, there are at least five different jQuery plugins named "datepicker". I still don't know about which one you are talking. You have to post details to what you are talking about. Would be nice to see a demo here.

Comment: I would assume the downvote is because your question wasn't clear what was being asked, and your attempt at clarification just made things more confusing.  It seems that you were asking why the alt text or similar was showing ellipses on mouseover, but you didn't state that.  Browser version probably would have helped as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

adding `'buttonText'=>'',` will solve the problem

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonText

Comment: Great, maybe a link to the documentation will help make this answer better : [jqueryui datepicker button text](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonText) .

Answer (score 0):

If you use traditional function,

you can use

```
buttonText : '',
```

Full example with cursor pointer, redirect with day, month and year:

```
<script> 
    $("#calendario").datepicker({
        buttonImage: '/images/calendario2.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',         
        buttonText : '',        
        onSelect: function(date, instance) {            
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            dia  = date.getDate(),  
            mes = date.getMonth() + 1,              
            agno =  date.getFullYear();
            window.location = "caja.php?dia="+dia + '&mes=' + mes + '&agno=' + agno;        }
     });        
     $( ".ui-datepicker-trigger" ).css('cursor','pointer');    
</script>
```